# g++ compile error

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++

I'm a newbie in Ubuntu.
I tried to compile a simple "Hello World!" c++ code in Ubuntu 11.04, with that code (in terminal):

```
gcc -Wall -W -Werror tex.cpp -o tex.
```

but compiler returned a lot of errors :

```
/tmp/ccL8c1p8.o: In function `main':
tex.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `std::cout'
tex.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/tmp/ccL8c1p8.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
tex.cpp:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
tex.cpp:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mohrd@mio:~$ gcc -Wall -W -Werror tex.cpp -o tex.
/tmp/ccEke5JP.o: In function `main':
tex.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `std::cout'
tex.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/tmp/ccEke5JP.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
tex.cpp:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
tex.cpp:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

simple code :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

Why? and what should I do???

many thanks ...

Comment: You're using gcc to compile a C++ program? Use g++.

Comment: You say g++ in the title, but use gcc in the body of the message - so which is it?

Comment: I'm newbie,really. and i don't know about difference between gcc and g++!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to use the g++ (or c++) command to compile your program, using "gcc" will compile it as c++ due to the .cpp extension but not link in the required c++ libraries.

Comment: Or add `-lstdc++` to the command line to link the standard C++ libraries.  But compiling with `g++` is the better solution.

Answer (score 6):

Use g++ instead of gcc for compiling C++ code:

```
g++ -Wall -W -Werror tex.cpp -o tex
```

gcc does not link stdc++ library by default which is required for your code.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `g++` command instead of `gcc`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`g++ -Wall hello.cpp -o hello`

Beacuse you are trying to compile `C++` code, not `C` code!

`-Wall` means `Warning ALL`, so you'll already see all the warnings

Also, name your programs and source files meaningfully!

LE: of course `-Werror` remains your choice

LE2: no need of `#include <algorithm>` in your code, so you can remove it!

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the same error for creating a giant arrary (50005) items. Be careful